# Is $ f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $, $f(x,y) = x^2-2y $ Surjective?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is $ f : \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} $, $f(x,y) = x^2-2y $ Surjective?

My work:

$f(x,y) = m = x^2-2y$

When $x=0$,

$m = -2y$

$y = -\dfrac{m}{2}$

$f(0,m) = 0-2(-\dfrac{m}{2})  = m $

Thus it is surjective. Is this sufficient. Am I missing anything?

Comment: This should work, yes. You've shown that for any given output there is an input that maps to it.

Comment: Did you mean "when $x=0$?" This does not work as it does not guarantee that $y$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: If $m$ is odd this does not work

Comment: On a positive side, you proved already the case when m is even. Now assume m is odd. You cannot choose x to be zero anymore.

Comment: You don’t know $m/2$ is an integer. Also, did you mean $x=0,$ not $y=0?$ And you say $f(0,m)=m?$ That is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $x=1$ and $y$ as integers $...0,1,....$ This will give all odd numbers as image. use $x=0$ and $y$ as integers $...0,1,2,..$this will give all even numbers as image. Hence surjective.

Answer (score 1):

If $m$ is even, take $x=0$ and $y=-m/2$, then $f(0,-m/2)=m$. If $m$ is odd, $m=2k+1$, and take $y=km$ and $x=m$, then $f(m,km)=m$.